# Changes in code only show after changing theme

Tags: code

I have a weird problem that happens only in one of my Wordpress sites (which is on a development server with many other wordpress sites that don't have this problem):

When I make changes in code - be it php, css or html - I can't just go to my site and refresh the pages for the changes to show up. I have to go to the themes page in the admin area, change to a different theme, then change back to the original theme, and only then can I refresh the page and see that changes I made.

Could it be a server configuration, something to do with caching? Or is it a plugin that might be causing the problem?

P.S
I don't even know how to tag this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, are there any caching plugins used on that site?..

Comment: Not from what I can tell...

Comment: I had a similar issue with a theme that was using TimThumb. I would have to go to my www folder and delete the files for the changes to take effect. I'm not sure what caused it ,but I eventually replaced timthumb to fix it.

Comment: i had that problem once and it was server cache, check your server configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I just remembered that this site is not on its own server. Edited the question. And @Jeremy - I don't have TimThumb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we disabled all plugins, then turned them on again, and miraculously - the problem disappeared :)